# HTTPS Display Mixed Content Error. Anyway to programatically handle this? or change the text of the error?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, https, uri

I have a HTTPS silverlight application (Finally), but i also have a call to get some map data from a non https website.

The issue is this call to the non https map data, which just consists of images (map tiles) and a list of countries.  It displays a note to the user saying that the page contains unsecured(mixed) content, and would they like to display it.

** The map data is hosted on a internal server on the network and is 100% trusted and secure content. **

My question is are these three:

1. Is there anyway i can tell the user that the unsecured content is only map data and will only be pulled to the client once, and if they want to see the map in the application, they should press accept?
2. Or is there a way to display a custom message to the user from silverlight and store their decision to hide or show the "unsafe" content in the app ?
3. Or is there a way in the config files to specify a set or URIs that are safe and can be ignored when the browser is doing its mixed content check?  Like if i wanted to specify a safe URI of http://mapdata.com/mapdata, could i do this along with some https setting in the webconfig file in silverlight?

Thanks for any help and time.

Comment: still looking for other answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, no you cannot overwrite that warning message. Imagine if a malicious site overwrote that message to say nothing was wrong? It's meant to be something developers can't mess with.

What you could do instead is tunnel the HTTP content over some HTTPS tunnel (maybe [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html)?). This will have some performance ramifications, but it should solve your mixed content issues.

Comment: So waht youre telling me is that every single https website in existance has only https links? like add links on gmail, hotmail bank sites etc... are all https?  I believe there is some way to handle the mixed content message.

Comment: @jordan.peoples The things you're describing are different. In the case of adds on gmail, those are links to other sites not content from them. The content is generated by Google. In the case of your maps content you're directly embedding http content in an https page. I'm sure my bank has no http links, they have no external links at all.

Comment: its a internal map server.  its the exact same thing as google's add system i believe.  I know this site is trusted becasue its internal on the network.  Hence why i asked the question if i can overwrite the base security checks , casue its a trusted website already...

Comment: @jordan.peoples If you control that resource, why not put it over HTTPS?

Comment: Well that would be more effort than we want to put in at this moment.  Im still wondering how all the other https sites do it.  they cant all be using all secure resrouces.... can they?

Comment: If any website isn't using HTTPS to provide all content loaded on their pages, then their users will get the same message. By design, the browser doesn't allow a website to suppress this message, as it could pose a potential security threat to the end-user; just like there is no way to pragmatically suppress UAC popups in Windows.

Comment: @jordan.peoples: Yes, they can. If you want to embed external (= different host) content on https, it should be https, too. If you have both, a http and a https variant, you can use protocol-less linking (`//example.com/foo.png`), *but* you'd have to offer it over https anyway.